# What page should json-ld for LocalBusiness be put on?

Tags: web, json-ld

I am currently building a website, and decided to use json-ld for providing some semantic information about the "LocalBusiness" (it is a non-profit organization). Of course, the main goal is to improve the search engine ranking, and provide more useful results to a user.

I have written the json-ld structure, and I then put it on the contact page. After some consideration, though, I moved it to the landing page (naked URL, the one that is pointed to inside the json-ld structure itself).

Is this the right page to put it on (according to the web crawlers' behavior), should I put it on more pages, or even on every web page (including the forum)?

Moreover, if this metadata is used by other clients (which I'm unsure of, at this point), such as screen readers, should it be also included on other webpages?

Comment: Currently it’s not clear according to which criteria this question should be answered. -- a) Structured data typically doesn’t affect the ranking in search engines at all. b) Screen readers typically don’t consume such structured data.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I stand a bit corrected (I guess it could change if we move towards a more semantic web, but that's irrelevant). Search engines typically use this information to display structured answers to user queries. I would like to make sure that such structured results are returned on a maximum number of queries (keywords related to the website), and I am therefore asking if the pages on which the json-ld structure is put usually has any effect on this. Not sure if I am clearer.

Comment: The search engines that display rich results based on Schema.org typically document how the structured data should be specified. So if you care about a specific rich result, it would be best to consult the search engine’s docs, and if anything is unclear, ask a question referencing that documentation (if the question is more SEO-related, [webmasters.se] might be better place, while Stack Overflow works fine if the question is more syntax-related). -- If you want to keep your general question, it might work to ask for a best practice from Schema.org/JSON-LD perspectives, without the SEO part.

Comment: @unor, This sounds likely, thanks. I did not find this one during my research, likely because I searched for "LocalBusiness" instead of "Organization" (which could be a better fit). The answer there answers my question, so I guess this one can be closed as a duplicate.